# SIMULINK: Managing (saving) variable state in embedded matlab function

Tags: matlab, simulink

Each time my MATLAB function is called it is stateless, so that I only have the values of my input variables. How I manage the state (i.e., values of variables) between cycles? For example, on step 100 I made some calculation, that I need to use on step 200. I would have used global variables, but they are not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `persistent` variables are for.
See `>>doc persistent` for more information, but basically you want the following

```
function y = fcn(u)

%define persistent variables
persistent a b c

% initialize persistent variables (at t=0)
if isempty(a)
   a = 1;
   b = 10;
   c = 12;
end


% update variables
a = a+7;
b = b+4;

% update out
y = u + a + b + c;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer was very helpful!